# Is CRYPT_SHA512 with iterations as strong as bcrypt (and related questions)

Tags: php, security, cryptography, kohana

I'm writing a first attempt at a user login system and would like to get it right. I feel I'm in duplicate territory here but for all my reading haven't been able to find a solid answer to a few questions. If I've missed something however, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

I will be using 128bit per user salts on all passwords, and enforcing "strong" (*subjective I know!*) passwords but can't work out what is the best way to hash them so,

1. Would using `CRYPT_SHA512` with iterations ever
   be as strong as using
   `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`?
2. <strike>Is there a</strike> What is the difference
   between CRYPT_SHA512 with
   iterations, and repeating
   `hash_hmac` using `sha512` a (large)
   number of times. Is one better than
   the other and which is recommended
   for hashing passwords? I ask because
   I'm using Kohana and the default
   `auth` implementation uses
   `hash_hmac`. I don't think it will
   be too hard to add iterations to
   that (and I'm going to have to
   modify it to add per user salts
   anyway), which leads me on to ..
3. Is there a module to do this already available for
   Kohana (3.1)? Before I go about writing my
   own, if there's something out there
   that is suitable I'd be happy to use
   that. So, something that performs
   hash stretching (be it bcrypt or
   sha512) and allows per user salts.
   And finally,

*... as pointed out in comments, question 4 is really a separate question entirely so I'm getting rid of it. Feel free to ignore it. The only reason I won't edit it out completely is that it is already referenced in an answer.*

<strike>4. My system will allow users with different privileges.
    Some will be administrators with
    full rights, some developers with
    slightly lesser rights, all the way
    down to anonymous users with rights
    to only leave comments for example.
    I haven't been able to find any
    information about this really. What
    is the "correct" way to store a user
    account type in the database. A
    naive first thought is that a simple
    integer in the user table would
    suffice, but I can't help thinking
    this is a terribly bad idea. If
    someone gets hold of the database it
    wouldn't be hard to work out which
    `int` represents an administrator,
    then they only need to brute force
    one password to gain full access
    rights. Would it suffice to simply
    hash the account type integer and
    store that, or should I be looking
    at another method?</strike>

Comment: 3. TRy this - https://github.com/shadowhand/bonafide

Comment: @biakaveron Thanks. I've looked at bonafide I'm not sure it quite fulfills my needs (not helped by the fact that the documentation doesn't seem to be in the userguide) but I'm just going over it again now.

Comment: 4 really should be in a different question to 1-3 - it's a completely separate question.

Comment: @Nick I agree. I guess I got a bit carried away when writing the question. I'm going to edit it to at least separate question four. I'd remove it entirely but since the current answer references it I think maybe I shouldn't. Thanks for keeping me on the straight and narrow though!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to questions 1-3 is really one answer, composed of several parts.

Firstly, you should be using a strong hash with per-user salts. In particular I would suggest PBKDF2 which is a useful system for this. That includes iteration.

Your reference to bcrypt is a bit different. Passwords should always be one-way hashed. You can use a function like PBKDF2 or a hmac to do this. You shouldn't use a reversible algorithm. *However* it is best if you can store the salt away from the hash itself. One suggestion for doing this is to bcrypt the salt with a key that is accessed from the file system, not the database. Preferably in a file with 600 permissions owned by someone other than the webserver user and loaded by setuid or the like. This way even if the database is compromised there still isn't enough information to derive the password.

Part 4 is about data structures to store ACLs. There are [lots of options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Kohana+acl) for that so have a look around for something which suits you. You might not need a full-blown ACL, instead just having user roles/groups or particular permission flags. This will depend on your application.

Comment: If you are interested in a PBKDF2 implementation for kohana, I have it in Vendo, which I use for user passwords: https://github.com/vendo/core/blob/develop/classes/auth.php#L51

Comment: bcrypt is a password hashing function, similar in intended use to PBKDF2. It uses a symmetric primitive, but it's not symmetric. Encrypting salts or otherwise using a 'secret salt' isn't best practice in any system I'm aware of, and only marginally strengthens your system against very specific attacks at the cost of a lot of additional system complexity.

Comment: @Nick see http://blog.mozilla.com/webappsec/2011/05/10/sha-512-w-per-user-salts-is-not-enough/ for an argument on secret salting (though I don't use it myself).

Comment: All these schemes rely on somehow being able to prevent the attacker from reading the secret key, which is a tall order (or requires some really contrived threat models) given they can already read your password hashes. The author of that article would be better off concentrating on strengthening his hashes with PBKDF2 or bcrypt!

Comment: @Nick I agree that good hashing is the most important element, but once you've got there, I think secret salting has advantages. In particular with web applications SQL injection/database leaks are far more common than filesystem disclosure. The two are really different methods of attack. If you can require both before passwords can be attacked, there's value in that.